# How to create a form in a pop-up using xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, popup, modal-dialog, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.forms and I need to have a login form in a popup view like in the following image:

[image: https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup/blob/master/pictures/androidPopup.gif?raw=true]

Right now I'm using PushModalAsync, however this makes the new page with the form cover the whole screen, instead of just showing a popup view as I want.

Is there any way to do this using xamarin.forms? If not, is there any cross-platform (Android, iOS and UWP) alternative already implemented?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709571/display-a-popup-with-xamarin-forms/51743006#51743006

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My experience says that XLabs' PopupLayout [doesn't work properly sometimes](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1107). But there is a really nice library which allow to create complex popups: [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup). The only problem: UWP implementation is missing (but it's [going to be released](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/tree/wp-uwp)).

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in this case uwp implementation is needed.

Comment: [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Prerelease (1.0.0-pre1) already supports WinPhone and UWP.

I would be glad if you accept participating in the beta testing.

Answer (score 4):

[XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) has a PopupLayout that you can use to do this.

```
var pop = new XLabs.Forms.Controls.PopupLayout();

// PatientSearch is a ContentView I was to display in the popup
var search = new PatientSearch(data, this);
search.WidthRequest = 600;
search.HeightRequest = 500;
search.BackgroundColor = new Color (1, 1, 1, 0.8);
pop.ShowPopup(search);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting an error NullReferenceException (https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1107#issuecomment-197701086). Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I use AbsoluteLayout to simulate popup.

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="rootLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainLayout" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <!-- Put your main contents-->
        </StackLayout>
        <ContentView x:Name="popupOverlay"
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}"
                     BackgroundColor="#C0808080"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout x:Name="popupContent"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         WidthRequest="200"
                         HeightRequest="200">
                <Entry Placeholder="UserName"></Entry>
                <Entry Placeholder="Password"></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

1. First, put the background contents i.e. main contents inside of an AbsoluteLayout
2. Second, Add a ContentView (popupOverlay) which will hold your form content as a child. This outer view should span across the entire screen with a semitransparent grayish background color (#**C0**808080).
3. Center the popup element layout (popupContent) inside of the overlay.
4. I also usually use a close button in the popupContent to hide it.
5. Show or Hide the popup by setting the IsVisible property of popupOverlay to true or false respectively.

Comment: this will make your ui heavy. it is not the best idea. you better use rg popups and once you are done with your work on the popup, you can dispose it but if you hide it, it is still there in the ui tree.

Comment: You are right. But It is an alternative a way of popup simulation.

Comment: I tried a similar approach but I'm encountering different problems: orientation change, size of the content, ... This is only a minimal demo for me, but yeah you have something like a popup in XF.

Comment: You should use grid instead of stack layout, that way you should have a more consistent layout on orientation changes.

Comment: I've been trying to achieve this for an hour! Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A common solution I have used is to used to solve this is to create a `StackLayout` with all the form inside and insert it a children of the Page you are currently using, for example:

```
PopupPage popUp; //This will be the layout of the form

Page : ContentPage {

    var gird = new Gird();

    popUp = PopupPage();
    popUp.IsVisible = false;

    var mainContainer = new StackLayout();

    mainContainer.Children.Add(All you UI stuff..);

    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

    grid.Children.Add(mainContainer,0,0);
    grid.Children.Add(popUp,0,0);

}
```

So in order to show the popoUP you need to play with the IsVisible property, for example:

```
void OnButtonClicked(){

    //You can center the popup using Vertical options or whatever you need
    //and to resize the pop up you can do different calculations like
    //popUp.Width = ScreenWidth / 2 and popUp.Height = ScreenWidth / 2
    popUp.IsVisile = true;

}
```

And this works for all platforms, the only disadvantage is that you will not have the transparent layout, but for that you can use:

https://github.com/gaborv/xam-forms-transparent-modal