# How to create a cross-platform popup dialog in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

In our Xamarin mobile app, I need to display a popup dialog that is timer based. Basically, if the user does not click on OK button, the dialog should still go away within ten seconds.

On the net, there are references to creating custom dialogs for Android and for iOS. However, I did not find any reference to creating a cross-platform dialog.

There seems to be a third party nuget package that creates popup dialogs -
 http://www.sparkhound.com/learn/blog/creating-a-modal-popup-dialog-in-xamarin-forms, However, I would prefer not to use a third party package. Plus, I don't know if the library supports timer-based dialogs.

Is there any way to create a simple cross-platform dialog? From usage perspective, here is the prototype I am thinking:

```
 static void DisplayAlert(string title, string body, int msec);
```

Comment: There is not a simple way to do this natively in XF.  You either need to write custom renderers to do it using the native platform UI, or use one of the available third party solutions that have already solved this for you.  "Plus I don't know if the library supports timer based dialogs" - why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Here you can get : https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

Here's a custom popup that I've created in Xamarin.Forms. It includes some fancy animations and even blurs the background. I've used it successfully in a couple apps that I've built.

You can trigger this custom popup by calling `ShowView`. It has a timer and will dismiss itself in 10 seconds, or you can dismiss it by calling `HideView`.

## Code

#### Custom Popup Base Class

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public abstract class OverlayContentView : ContentView
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        readonly BoxView _backgroundOverlayBoxView;
        readonly Frame _overlayFrame;
        readonly RelativeLayout _relativeLayout;
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        View _overlayContent;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        protected OverlayContentView(bool isChildOfNavigationPage)
        {
            _backgroundOverlayBoxView = new BoxView
            {
                BackgroundColor = ColorConstants.WhiteWith75Opacity
            };
            _backgroundOverlayBoxView.Opacity = 0;

            _overlayFrame = new Frame
            {
                HasShadow = true,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White
            };
            _overlayFrame.Scale = 0;

            _relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
            Func<RelativeLayout, double> getOverlayContentHeight = (p) => OverlayContent.Measure(p.Width, p.Height).Request.Height;
            Func<RelativeLayout, double> getOverlayContentWidth = (p) => OverlayContent.Measure(p.Width, p.Height).Request.Width;

            _relativeLayout.Children.Add(_backgroundOverlayBoxView,
                   Constraint.Constant(-10),
                   Constraint.Constant(0),
                  Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width + 20),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height)
               );
            _relativeLayout.Children.Add(_overlayFrame,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - getOverlayContentWidth(parent) / 2 - 25),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent =>
                    {
                        switch (isChildOfNavigationPage)
                        {
                            case true:
                                return parent.Height / 4 - getOverlayContentHeight(parent) / 2;

                            default:
                                return parent.Height / 2 - getOverlayContentHeight(parent) / 2 - 10;
                        }
                    }),

                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => getOverlayContentWidth(parent) + 50),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => getOverlayContentHeight(parent) + 40)
              );
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public View OverlayContent
        {
            get => _overlayContent;
            set
            {
                _overlayContent = value;
                _overlayContent.Scale = 0;

                _overlayFrame.Content = _overlayContent;

                Content = _relativeLayout;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void ShowView(bool shouldDisappearAfterTimeoutExpires = false, int timeoutInSeconds = 10)
        {
            const uint overlayContentViewAnimationTime = 300;
            const double overlayContentViewMaxSize = 1.05;
            const double overlayContentViewNormalSize = 1;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                IsVisible = true;
                _backgroundOverlayBoxView.Opacity = 1;

                await Task.WhenAll(OverlayContent?.ScaleTo(overlayContentViewMaxSize, overlayContentViewAnimationTime, Easing.CubicOut),
                                    _overlayFrame?.ScaleTo(overlayContentViewMaxSize, overlayContentViewAnimationTime, Easing.CubicOut));

                await Task.WhenAll(OverlayContent?.ScaleTo(overlayContentViewNormalSize, overlayContentViewAnimationTime, Easing.CubicOut),
                                    _overlayFrame?.ScaleTo(overlayContentViewNormalSize, overlayContentViewAnimationTime, Easing.CubicOut));

                if (!shouldDisappearAfterTimeoutExpires)
                    return;

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));

                HideView();
            });
        }

        public void HideView()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await this.FadeTo(0);

                IsVisible = false;
                InputTransparent = true;
                Opacity = 1;

                _backgroundOverlayBoxView.Opacity = 0;
                OverlayContent.Scale = 0;
                _overlayFrame.Scale = 0;
            });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### Implementation of Custom Popup

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class WelcomeView : OverlayContentView
    {
        public WelcomeView() : base(true)
        {
            const string titleText = "Welcome";
            const string bodyText = "Enjoy InvestmentDataSampleApp";
            const string okButtonText = "Ok, thanks!";

            var titleLabel = new Label
            {
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                Text = titleText,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            var bodyLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = bodyText,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            var okButton = new Button
            {
                TextColor = Color.White,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                Margin = new Thickness(5),
                Text = okButtonText,
                BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BorderWidthProperty = 1,
                BorderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
            };
            okButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => this.HideView();

            var textAndButtonStack = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Spacing = 20,
                Children = {
                    titleLabel,
                    bodyLabel,
                    okButton
                }
            };

            OverlayContent = textAndButtonStack;
        }
    }
}
```

## Sample App

For reference, here's a sample app that has implemented the custom popup:
https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp

[image]

Comment: Will this work for every type of content e.g. `ListView`? Especially, I don't know if this `OverlayContent.Measure(p.Width, p.Height).Request.Height` would measure the correct size? That the dialog is centered should be a matter of the right calculation?

Comment: @testing You want to put a ListView in the pop up?

Comment: Different types of control, but yeah `ListView` is one of them. I think In this special case you must supply a size?

Comment: Yes, this example will work for any control. In general, I don't recommend putting a ListView inside of any layout; it's best to only use ListView as the `Content` of the `ContentPage`.

Comment: Feel free to try it, and if it doesn't work, open a new question Stack Overflow. I'd be happy to help you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at this post, i answered some time ago: [Display a popup with xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709571/display-a-popup-with-xamarin-forms/51743006#51743006)

Even though such a system takes some time to implement, it gives you the advantage to call any dialog from anywhere in your app without having to embed the dialog inside your content page(s).

If you want to have your dialog timed, you could simply call it with

```
Dialogs.ShowLoading();
Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => { Dialogs.Hide();
    return false;
});
```