# Partial screen page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a Xamarin Forms newbie so bear with me!
Is there a way in Xamarin Forms to create a page that only fills part of the screen? Like a pop up containing custom content that you define in the xaml. It must be in it's own page, not added to the layout of the parent page. I've been researching this for a while but have come up against a brick wall. I've done this previously in a native Android project and I now need to do it in my Xamarin Forms project.

Comment: I would look at [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) it's probably the easiest way to implement what you're wanting to do.

Comment: I have answered a similar question over here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709571/display-a-popup-with-xamarin-forms/51743006#51743006