# How to make UI changes while loading next screen in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms

I have a screen that takes some time to load. All I want to do is display a simple "Now Loading" message before the next screen loads. How do I achieve this? Here is the code I currently have trying to accomplish this:

```
void BT_User_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start a new task (this launches a new thread)
       var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do some work on a background thread, allowing the UI to remain responsive
            Navigation.PushAsync(new UserList());                
        });

        BT_User.IsEnabled = false;
        BT_User.Text = "Now Loading";        
    }
```

When running this code it Almost achieves what I want. It displays the "Now Loading" text, and in the background, it calls the next screen(I can see this only by setting a breakpoint in the load of the next screen). Problem is, the next screen never shows itself. I'm guessing this is because it is loaded on a background thread but not the main UI thread.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you throw in a new Screen from a background thread, it won't work. Changes in the UI need to be done in the Main UI Thread.

However Xamarin.Forms provides you with a helper:

In your background thread simply call:

```
var t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Do some work on a background thread, allowing the UI to remain responsive
    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new UserList());
    });             
});
```

Regarding your Loading overlay, you either need a plugin capable of handling popup dialogs (for instance Acr.UserDialogs) or you need to implement your own dialog system, if you don't want to be dependent on third party libraries.

I already have done the latter and provided a brief explanation on how to do it over here:
[Display a popup with xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709571/display-a-popup-with-xamarin-forms/51743006#51743006)