# PushModalAsync Xamarin forms with transparent background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a popOverPage with transparent light black background color.. I set the background color to transparent color then also I am not able to see the previous page content...

I did something like this

```
        var popOverPage = new PopOverPage();

        Navigation.PushModalAsync(popOverPage);
```

And then on the nextPage.

```
 BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But its not working.. It's showing background as white.
Can You Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: use https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: @Jason Thanks Looks Nice.

Comment: You can also try this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color/39164921#39164921

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159573/xamarin-forms-content-page-make-background-color-transparent/61504256#61504256)

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this in my project and that has worked pretty great, but it only works if you are using PushModalAsync() otherwise it just creates a solid background.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: This works well on Android. Thanks @Keenan!